# Access to fetch at '(url)' from origin '(localhost)' has been blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Estoy trabajando con React, haciendo un pequeño proyecto de practica que consulta a una API de imagenes y devuelve... pues la imagen.

La API es de Wallhaven. Al hacer la peticion desde Postman me regresa exactamente la informacion que busco, pero cuando intento hacerlo desde React obtengo este mensaje en la consola:

> Access to fetch at 'https://wallhaven.cc/api/v1/search?sorting=random'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

¿A que se debe o como puedo corregirlo?

Este es mi codigo al momento de hacer la peticion:

```
// Hacer peticion a la API
const api = await fetch('https://wallhaven.cc/api/v1/search?sorting=random');
// Obtener Respuesta
const wallpapers = await api.json();
console.log(wallpapers)
```

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) puedes pasarle una propiedad `mode: cors`

```
fetch('https://wallhaven.cc/api/v1/search?sorting=random',
 { method: 'GET',
   headers: misCabeceras,
   mode: 'cors', // <---
   cache: 'default'
})
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch#suministrando_opciones_de_petici%C3%B3n) al hacer el fetch tenés que agregarle lo siguiente:

El método fetch() puede aceptar opcionalmente un segundo parámetro, un objeto init que permite controlar un numero de diferentes ajustes:

mode acepta: 'cors', 'no-cors', '*cors', 'same-origin'

```
const api = await fetch('https://wallhaven.cc/api/v1/search?sorting=random', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-type': 'application/json'}),
        mode: 'no-cors'
});
```

Tenga en cuenta que mode: "no-cors" solo permite un conjunto limitado de encabezados en la solicitud:

- Accept
- Accept-Language
- Content-Language
- Content-Type with a value of: application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
  multipart/form-data, or text/plain

Comment: Para mejorar la respuesta, podés explicar brevemente qué dice la documentación al respecto.

Comment: Según el propio enlace que expones,  el método `GET` es un valor por defecto dado eso se asume que no es necesario declararlo